# How does the recent discovery of "microbes living 2,400m beneath the seabed off Japan" impact the search for life in our solar system?

Tags: life, solar-system

A recent BBC news article reports on finding [microbes living 2,400m beneath the seabed off Japan](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-30489814)

> The team found that microbes, despite having no light, no oxygen, barely any water and very limited nutrients, thrived in the cores.

Is this a significant enough difference from our expectations of habitable environments to alter how and where we might search for life in our solar system?

Comment: I don't think it is unexpected. Thus far, life has been found on Earth EVERYWHERE there's liquid water! There are microbes to which oxygen gas is lethal, and which live off nuclear radiation. C, O, N, H are among the most common elements in the universe. They can be combined in any way. There will be a solution to how for them to survive in many planetary environments.

Comment: And we may be surprised at where there may be water on Earth. Diamond-borne Ice VII gives evidence of molecular $\text{H}_2\text{O}$ in the deep mantle, though that would be too hot for life as we know it.